# function to delete elements selected linked list C

Tags: c, linked-list, nodes

Hi I'm creating a program for school where I have to:

1. Create structures
2. Create functions to print my linked list
3. Create functions to insert an ordered element
4. Delete elements with a minor year less than the year selected
   I created all a part the last one step.
   Can you help me to know what is the right way?
   This is my code:

STRUCTURE:

```
typedef struct dimension {
    int height;
    int length;
} DIMENSION;

typedef struct pic {
    DIMENSION d;
    char name[50];
    int year;
} PIC;

typedef struct node {
    PIC p;
    struct node *next;
} NODE;
```

PRINT LIST:

```
void printPic(PIC p) {
    printf("Autor: %s\nDimension\nHeight: %d\nLength: %d\nYear: %d\n", p.name, p.d.height, p.d.length, p.year);
}

void printList(NODE *head) {
    if(head->next==NULL) {
        printf("No element in the list!\n");
    } else {
        while(head->next != NULL) {
            head = head->next;
            printPic(head->p);
        }
    }
}
```

NEW PIC(ORDERED WITH AREA DIMENSION)

```
int area(PIC p) {
    return (p.d.height * p.d.length);
}

PIC createPic() {
    PIC newPic;
    
    printf("Author: ");
    fgets(newPic.name, 50, stdin);
    newPic.name[strlen(newPic.name)-1] = '\0';
    printf("Height: ");
    scanf("%d", &newPic.d.height);
    printf("\n");
    printf("Length: ");
    scanf("%d", &newPic.d.length);
    printf("\n");
    printf("Year: ");
    scanf("%d", &newPic.year);
    printf("\n");
    printf("\n");
    
    return newPic;
    
}

void insertPic(NODE *head) {
    
    NODE* newNode = malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    newNode->p = createPic();
    newNode->next = NULL;
    
    if(head==NULL) {
        head = newNode;
    } else {
        if(area(newNode->p) < area(head->p)) {
            newNode->next = head;
            head = newNode;
        } else {
            while(head->next != NULL && (area(newNode->p) > area(head->next->p))) {
                head = head->next;
            }
            newNode->next = head->next;
            head->next = newNode;
        }
    }
    
}
```

DELETE ELEMENTS WITH A MINOR YEAR THAN SELECTED YEAR:

**Edited and now it works:**

```
    void deletePic(NODE *head, int year) {
    if(head==NULL) {
        printf("No element in the list!\n");
    } else {
        while(head->next != NULL) {
            if(head->next->p.year < year) {
                NODE *p = head->next;
                head->next = p->next;
                free(p);
            } else {
                head = head->next;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

MAIN:

```
int main() {
    
    NODE *head = malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    head->next = NULL;
    int choice = -1;
    
    while(choice != 0) {
        printf("Select an action:\n");
        printf("Press 1 --> See list\n");
        printf("Press 2 --> Insert a new element\n");
        printf("Press 3 --> Delete elements with a minor year\n");
        printf("Press 0 --> Stop program\n");
        scanf("%d%*c", &choice);
        
        if(choice==1) {
            printList(head);
        }
        else if(choice==2) {
            insertPic(head);
        }
        else if(choice==3) {
            int year;
            printf("Choose an year\nAll elements with a smaller year will be eliminated\n");
            scanf("%d", &year);
            deletePic(head, year);
        }
        else if(choice==0) {
            printf("See you soon ;)\n");
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: When you do `yearNode->p.year = year` the pointer `yearNode` doesn't actually point anywhere. Dereferencing the pointer leads to *undefined behavior* (and likely crashes). You don't even need `yearNode`, just compare `head->next->p.year !=  year` directly.

Comment: @WhozCraig Do you mean only the delete function or all?The delete function I know that is completely wrong

Comment: That's the gaping hole, yes. If the menu is to be believed, you want that to delete all nodes less than the specified year, right? Even if you fix the pointer mistakes, `!=` isn't the way to do that; `<` would seem more appropriate.

Comment: As for the "removing" part, you have the previous node (which is `head`), the node to be removed (which is `head->next`) and the next node (which is `head->next->next`). Now draw a simple list out on paper using boxes for the nodes and arrows for the pointers. How should you manipulate the arrows (pointers) to "remove" a node from the list?

Comment: ok thanks @WhozCraig but I don't understand how to link nodes after removing one

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I tried(I edited my question with edited function)but doesn't work.MaybeI didn't linked with the right way nodes

Comment: Side note: writing in ALL CAPITAL LETTERS is unreadable and considered as rude. There are enough other alternatives like bold or italic, but these shouldn't be abused either

Comment: `free(head->next->next);` is wrong. You need to save **`head->next`** *before* removing it, so you can pass it to `free`.

Comment: Other side node: the design is somewhat wrong here, an empty list should have no head at all.

Comment: Last side node from me: instead of posting multiple code snippets with mostly redundant titles you should just post a [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `deletePic` function is broken in multiple places. Among them:

- Dereferencing an indeterminate pointer, `yearNode`
- Incorrect comparator (should use `<` ; not `!=`
- `free`'ing an indeterminate pointer.

The first and last of those are a recipe for disaster. If that function does what the menu claims it should, I *think* what you want is this:

```
void deletePic(NODE *head, int year)
{
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        printf("No element in the list!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        while (head->next != NULL)
        {
            if (head->next->p.year < year)
            {
                NODE *p = head->next;
                head->next = p->next;
                free(p);
            }
            else
            {
                head = head->next;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.I was a lot confused about this and I complicated my thoughts.Thanks all for your help!